# Loading Javascript Only When Specific Content Existing in a Post?

Tags: javascript, conditional-content

I'm trying to add Javascript for my *"PrettyPhoto"* plugin to pages only when their content contains  `rel='prettyPhoto'`. This looks very simple to me but all solutions I've found on the internet doesn't work for me. One example is:

```
<?php
function load_my_js() {
  if(is_admin() ) return; // never mind if this is an admin page
  global $post;
  if (strpos($post->post_content,'rel="prettyPhoto') == false) return
  wp_register_script('js_test',plugins_url().'/demo/test.js',array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('js_test');
}
add_action('wp','load_my_js');
?>
```

Another one from Yoast:

```
function yst_conditional_thickbox() {
  global $post;
  if (is_singular() &&
    strpos($post->post_content,'class="thickbox"') !== false) {
      wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
  }
}
add_action('wp_print_styles','yst_conditional_thickbox');
```

Maybe you know how to do this? Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

This is how looks your code:

```
class UglyPhotoPlugin {
  static function on_load() {
    add_action('wp',array(__CLASS__,'load_my_js'));
  }
  static function load_my_js() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
      global $post;
      if (strpos($post->post_content,'rel="prettyPhoto"') !== false) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'prettyJs', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
      }
    }
  }
}
UglyPhotoPlugin::on_load();
```

HTML output:

```
We are here!stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 17
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2009-12-25 17:10:18
    [post_date_gmt] => 2009-12-25 17:10:18
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => Portfolio
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => portfolio
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2010-12-21 00:24:59
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2010-12-21 00:24:59
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://mysite.com/?page_id=17
    [menu_order] => 3
    [post_type] => page
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [ancestors] => Array
        (
        )

    [filter] => raw
)
```

This code is generated above `!DOCTYPE`.
Am I right?

Comment: This is similar to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/conditionally-loading-javascript-css-for-shortcodes

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what exactly your code is doing wrong but here's code that does it right. I've decided to wrap the code in a class to be used for your plugin, and for humor I called it *"Ugly Photo Plugin."*  Here's the full code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ugly Photo Plugin
*/
class UglyPhotoPlugin {
  static function on_load() {
    add_action('wp',array(__CLASS__,'wp'));
    add_shortcode('ugly-photo',array(__CLASS__,'ugly_photo_shortcode'));
  }
  static function ugly_photo_shortcode($attributes,$content,$code) {
    return '<div rel="ugly-photo">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  static function wp() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
      global $post;
      if (strpos($post->post_content,'[ugly-photo]') !== false) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_test', 
          plugins_url('/demo/test.js',__FILE__), 
          array('jquery') );
      }
    }
  }
}
UglyPhotoPlugin::on_load();
```

Note that I've decided to use a shortcode `[ugly-photo]` and am testing for it instead of `'rel="prettyPhoto"'` because WordPress' WYSIWYG TinyMCE editor will strip out the `"rel"` value from your `<div>` so using the shortcode solves that problem.

Here's what the post looks like when editing:

[image: WordPress Post Editor with 'Ugly Photo' Shortcode]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Edit_Post_%E2%80%B9_PM-Sherpa_%E2%80%94_WordPress-20101225-004111.jpg))</sub>

Here's what my Javascript File has in it and where I've located it:

[image: https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101225-004514.jpg]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101225-004514.jpg))</sub>

And finally here is the result:

[image: Conditional Loading of Javascript in WordPress]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101225-003608.jpg))</sub>

P.S. Happy Holidays!

Comment: I can't understand how to add this code to my purpose.
The main purpose of the prettyPhoto plugin is to load images into popup window. For this we must add for all images `rel="prettyPhoto"` attribute and link after this looks like this:
`<a href="/big_image.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="/small_images.jpg" alt="" /></a>` . My portfolio template already include `rel="prettyPhoto"` for all images. I just want to check if a page exist `rel="prettyPhoto"`, if yes include `prettyPhoto.js`. Yes, later I can add images to post/page by hand with `rel="prettyPhoto"` attributes.
My name is Denis:)

Comment: @Denis: Then just replace `strpos($post->post_content,'[ugly-photo]'` with `strpos($post->post_content,'rel="prettyPhoto"'` and just don't use the shortcode. *(BTW, can I assume you are not a programmer and are just copying and pasting code rather than using it as a study aid to learn how to do these things yourself? I'm not challenging, I just want to learn what your skill level is because I'd answer differently for a copy-and-paster than for a developer.)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - At the moment I only acquire programming, but the copy / paste does not do. I'm trying to understand how works that or another code, but do not always have enough knowledge. Please edit my name in answer, in my language it sounds ugly. Thanks.

Comment: @Denis - Sorry about the name typo, fixed (what is your language? You understand English better than I understand yours. :) So did this answer help you?

Comment: again mike rocks! :D

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Sorry for my poor English! My language is russian and ukrainian. This code didn't work for me. I paste this code into my main functions file, but nothing. I think something is preventing the execution of this code. I'm update the question.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - Why did you add action for `'wp_print_scripts'` instead of `'init'` as in my example?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I tried `wp`, `wp_print_scripts`, `wp_head`, `the_header` = NOTHING.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - What evidence do you have for NOTHING? You don't see your script work, or have you viewed the source in browser and don't see the `<link>` generated in the HTML output? If it shows up in `<link>` have you verified that the URL is correct, i.e. have you used your browser to download the .JS file? Could it be an error in your Javascript instead? Also, where are you putting the code, in a plugin or your theme's `functions.php` file? If a plugin, why do you used ` get_bloginfo('template_directory')`?  Is there a chance you are using Child Theme?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - As I said above I put this code into my `functions.php`. I don't see the `<link>` generated in the HTML output. Is there any way to check whats wrong with my theme and with your example?

Comment: @Denis Belousov - To start, right before `if (!is_admin())` put an `echo "We are here!";` to see if it even executes. After `global $post;` put a `print_r($post);`. Also, you didn't answer about Child theme? Lastly, you are using WordPress 3.0.x, right?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Version of Wordpress is 3.0.1 . No, it's not a Child theme. HTML output in edited question.

Comment: @Denis Belousov - Your page titled "Portfolio" has no content according to your output so it could not contain `'rel="prettyPhoto"'` because, it has no content! Do you not see the problem?  Can you give me the URL for the page you are working on?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - At the moment my site is on the local machine. I don't know why it has no content, because I see my posts on the page. I has portfolio template with `query_posts('cat=5')`, maybe your plugin only work when content is putting in WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: @Denis Belousov - My plugin is very, very simple. I'm 99% sure you have something that is conflicting and causing it to fail. Why not download the PhpStorm 2.0 beta and ZendDebugger so you can trace through to figure out your issue like I would do if I had your site on my local machine?  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP It's the absolute best tool you'll find for resolve issues like this.