# Conditionally Loading JavaScript/CSS for Shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, customization, wp-enqueue-style

I released a plugin that creates a shortcode and requires a JavaScript file and a CSS file to load on any page that contains that shortcode. I could just make the script/style load on all pages, but that's not the best practice. I only want to load the files on pages that call the shortcode. I've found two methods of doing this, but both have problems.

[Method 1](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html) sets a flag to true inside the shortcode handler function, and then checks that value inside a `wp_footer` callback. If it's true, it uses `wp_print_scripts()` to load the JavaScript. The problem with this is that it only works for JavaScript and not CSS, because CSS should be declared inside `<head>`, which you can only do during an early hook like `init` or `wp_head`.

[Method 2](http://beerpla.net/2010/01/13/wordpress-plugin-development-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-conditionally-and-only-when-needed-by-the-posts/) fires early and "peeks ahead" to see if the shortcode exists in the current page content. I like this method much better than the first, but the problem with it it won't detect if the template calls `do_shortcode()`.

So, I'm leaning towards using the second method and then trying to detect if a template is assigned, and if so, parse it for the shortcode. Before I do that, though, I wanted to check if anyone knows of a better method.

**Update:** I've integrated the solution into my plugin. If anyone is curious to see it fleshed out in a live environment you can [download it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/basic-google-maps-placemarks) or [browse it](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/basic-google-maps-placemarks/).

**Update 2:** As of WordPress 3.3, it's now possible to [call `wp_enqueue_script()` directly inside a shortcode callback](http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html), and the JavaScript file will be called within the document's footer. That's technically possible for CSS files as well, but should be considered a bad practice because outputting CSS outside the `<head>` tag violates W3C specs, can case FOUC, and may force the browser to re-render the page.

Comment: I've used a variation of Method 1 in the past. Load JS for the shortcode in the footer, load CSS for the shortcode in-line. It works, but is hackish. Looking forward to a better solution.

Comment: The main problems with inline CSS are that it is difficult to override with other styles, and it doesn't use the wp_enqueue_styles() method.

Comment: How much css do you have?

Comment: How many lines of javascript?

Comment: It's about 30 lines of CSS and 100 lines of JavaScript, but that's irrelevant. They need to be included the RIGHT way, regardless of size. See the comments on the answers for the reasons why.

Comment: The javascript is the easy part. Best wat to do this is under "Jedi" here: http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

Comment: 30 lines is not very much, I would minify it an print it to the head in a style tag in all views. Provide a filter and/or setting enabling user to disable styles if they want to.

Comment: @mfields, I already know about that method, I linked to it in the question... Please read RTFQ before commenting ;)

Comment: Then you already know the BEST way to handle the javascript ;) The BEST way inmo to deal with the css is to "30 lines is not very much, I would minify it an print it to the head in a style tag in all views. Provide a filter and/or setting enabling user to disable styles if they want to." If you need to use wp_enqueue_script() go right ahead, I do not feel that it is necessary though as it adds another http request. Minify -> print at wp_head() -> allow other extension to filter output.

Comment: I think separate files is cleaner and better organization. Minification can be done by the server at runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on my own experience, I've used a combination of method 1 & 2 - the architecture and footer scripts of 1, and the 'look-ahead' technique of 2.

For the look-ahead though, I use regex in place of `stripos`; personal preference, faster, and can check for 'malformed' shortcode;

```
preg_match( '#\[ *shortcode([^\]])*\]#i', $content );
```

If you're concerned about authors using `do_shortcode` manually, I would opt to instruct them to <strike>use an action call</strike> enqueue your pre-registered style manually.

**UPDATE**: For the lazy author who never RTFM, output a message to highlight the **error** of their ways ;)

```
function my_shortcode()
{
    static $enqueued;
    if ( ! isset( $enqueued ) )
        $enqueued = wp_style_is( 'my_style', 'done' ); // cache it so we don't repeat if called over and over

    // do shortcode
    $output = '';

    if ( ! $enqueued )
        // you can output the message on first occurence only by wrapping it in the previous if
        $output .= <<<HTML
<p>Attention! You must enqueue the shortcode stylesheet yourself if calling <code>do_shortcode()</code> directly!</p>
<p>Use <code>wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style' );</code> before your <code>get_header()</code> call inside your template.</p>
HTML;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. Ideally I'd like it to work without them having to do anything extra -- because half the time they probably won't read the FAQ first, so they'll just assume it's broken -- but I might end up doing that. I could register the scripts on every page, but only enqueue them if I detect a shortcode. Then, users could hook into init and call the enqueue functions in specific templates where needed, assuming it's not already too late in the execution at that point. Also, WP has get_shortcode_regex() built-in.

Comment: If users are adept at implementing `do_shortcode()`, is it not reasonable to assume that they are likewise adept at following instructions for enqueueing the shortcode style?

Comment: True, but it'll get the regex for *all* shortcodes, not just yours ;) "I could register the scripts on every page" Probably the better method too! Note they don't need to hook into `init`, just anywhere before `wp_head`. For the lazy developer, check `wp_style_is( 'my_style_handle', 'done' )` inside your shortcode. If it's false, print out a visible error that instructs them what to do.

Comment: @Chip - I'm not worried that they're not _capable_ of following the instructions, just that they won't know they're supposed to, since 99% of the time you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: @Ian my thinking was that adding `do_shortcode()` to the template is *already* "do[ing] something extra" - and users that would do that something-extra would either already know about the need to enqueue the style, or else would be more willing/likely to follow special instructions.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - I got it integrated with my code and updated the question w/ links to it in case anyone wants to see it fleshed out. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @Ian Nice! Thanks for coming back with an update, both for us and the googlers that land on it later ;)

Comment: Nice but i have to disagree on the `preg_match` beeing faster the `strpos` http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm

Comment: @Bainternet Not neccessarily - [`preg_match` vs `stripos` (case-insensitive)](http://pastebin.com/nbKF661C)  - either way we're talking petty timings. In hindsight, I think I should have avoided the term "faster" - really I was trying to imply it was more *efficient* for the task in hand (as opposed to multiple `stripos` for accomodating various shortcode formats).

Answer (score 9):

I'm late answering this question but since Ian started [this thread](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2013-January/045050.html) on the wp-hackers list today it made me think it worth answering especially considering I've been planning to add such a feature to some plugins I've been working on.

An approach to consider is to check on the first page load to see if the shortcode is actually used and then save the shortcode usage status to a post meta key.  Here's how:

### Step-by-Step How-To

1. Set a `$shortcode_used` flag to `'no'`.
2. In the shortcode function itself set the `$shortcode_used` flag to `'yes'`.
3. Set a `'the_content'` hook priority `12` which is after WordPress has processed shortcodes and check post meta for a `''` using the key `"_has_{$shortcode_name}_shortcode"`. *(A value of `''` is returned when a post meta key doesn't exist for the post ID.)*
4. Use a `'save_post'` hook to delete the post meta clearing the persistent flag for that post in case the user changes shortcode usage.
5. Also in the `'save_post'` hook use `wp_remote_request()` to send a non-blocking HTTP GET to the post's own permalink to trigger to first page load and the setting of the persistent flag.
6. Lastly set a `'wp_print_styles'` and check post meta for a value of `'yes'`, `'no'` or `''` using the key `"_has_{$shortcode_name}_shortcode"` . If the value is `'no'` don't serve the external. If the value is `'yes'` or `''` go ahead and serve the external.

And that should do it. I've written and tested an example plugin to show how this all works.

### Example Plugin Code

The plugin wakes up on a `[trigger-css]` shortcode which sets the `<h2>` elements on the page to white-on-red so you can easily see it working. It assumes a `css` subdirectory containing `style.css` file with this CSS in it:

```
/*
 * Filename: css/style.css
 */
h2 {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

And below is the code in a working plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: CSS on Shortcode
 * Description: Shows how to conditionally load a shortcode
 * Author: Mike Schinkel <mike@newclarity.net>
 */
class CSS_On_Shortcode {

  /**
   * @var CSS_On_Shortcode
   */
  private static $_this;

  /**
   * @var string 'yes'/'no' vs. true/false as get_post_meta() returns '' for false and not found.
   */
  var $shortcode_used = 'no';

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  var $HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY = '_has_trigger-css_shortcode';
  /**
   *
   */
  function __construct() {
    self::$_this = $this;
    add_shortcode( 'trigger-css', array( $this, 'do_shortcode' ) );
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content' ), 12 ); // AFTER WordPress' do_shortcode()
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_print_styles', array( $this, 'wp_print_styles' ) );
  }

  /**
   * @return CSS_On_Shortcode
   */
  function this() {
    return self::$_this;
  }

  /**
   * @param array $arguments
   * @param string $content
   * @return string
   */
  function do_shortcode( $arguments, $content ) {
    /**
     * If this shortcode is being used, capture the value so we can save to post_meta in the 'the_content' filter.
     */
    $this->shortcode_used = 'yes';
    return '<h2>THIS POST WILL ADD CSS TO MAKE H2 TAGS WHITE ON RED</h2>';
  }

  /**
   * Delete the 'has_shortcode' meta value so that it can be regenerated
   * on first page load in case shortcode use has changed.
   *
   * @param int $post_id
   */
  function save_post( $post_id ) {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $this->HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY );
    /**
     * Now load the post asynchronously via HTTP to pre-set the meta value for $this->HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY.
     */
    wp_remote_request( get_permalink( $post_id ), array( 'blocking' => false ) );
  }

  /**
   * @param array $args
   *
   * @return array
   */
  function wp_print_styles( $args ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'no' != get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY, true ) ) {
      /**
       * Only bypass if set to 'no' as '' is unknown.
       */
      wp_enqueue_style( 'css-on-shortcode', plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
   }

  /**
   * @param string $content
   * @return string
   */
  function the_content( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( '' === get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY, true ) ) {
      /**
       * This is the first time the shortcode has ever been seen for this post.
       * Save a post_meta key so that next time we'll know this post uses this shortcode
       */
      update_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->HAS_SHORTCODE_KEY, $this->shortcode_used );
    }
    /**
     * Remove this filter now. We don't need it for this post again.
     */
    remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content' ), 12 );
    return $content;
  }

}
new CSS_On_Shortcode();
```

### Example Screenshots

Here's a series of screenshots

#### Basic Post Editor, No Content

[image]

#### Post Display, No Content

[image]

#### Basic Post Editor with `[trigger-css]` Shortcode

[image]

#### Post Display with `[trigger-css]` Shortcode

[image]

### Not Sure if it's 100%

I believe the above should work in almost all cases but as I just wrote this code I can't be 100% sure. If you can find situations where it doesn't work I'd really like to know so I can fix the code in some plugins I just added this to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So five plugins using your approach will trigger five remote requests each time a post is saved? I’d rather use a regex on `post_content`. And what about shortcodes in widgets?

Comment: @toscho The triggering of post loading is actually optional; it's only there to ensure a user doesn't have to see the first page load with the externals loaded. It's also a non-blocking call so in theory you shouldn't notice it. For our code we are doing in a base class so the base class can handles doing it only once. We could hook the `'pre_http_request'` hook and disable multiple calls to the same URL while the `'save_post'` hook is active, but I'd want to wait until w really saw a need for that, no? As for Widgets it could be enhanced to handle but it's not a use-case I've looked at yet.

Comment: @toscho - Also you can't be sure that the shortcode is there as another hook may clear it. The only way you can be sure is if the shortcode function actually fires. So the regex approach isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: I know. There is **no** bullet-proof way to inject CSS for shortcodes (except using `<style>`).

Comment: I'm working with an implementation based on this solution and I just wanted to point out that this method will not enqueue for a post/page preview.

Comment: My solution to the preview issue: https://gist.github.com/mor7ifer/e50a9864a372a05b4a3b

Answer (score 6):

Googling found me a *potential* [answer](http://www.nicolaskuttler.com/post/shortcodes-include-css-and-js-only-on-the-correct-blog-pages/).  I say "potential" as in it looks good, should work, but I'm not 100% convinced it's the best way to do it:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'yourplugin_include_css' );
function yourplugin_include_css() {
    // Check if shortcode exists in page or post content
    global $post;

    // I removed the end ' ] '... so it can accept args.
    if ( strstr( $post->post_content, '[yourshortcode ' ) ) {
        echo $csslink;
    }
}
```

This should be able to check if the current post is using a shortcode and add a stylesheet to the `<head>` element appropriately.  But I don't think it will work for an index (i.e. multiple posts in the loop) page ...  It's also from a 2-yr old blog post, so I'm not even sure it will work with WP 3.1.X.

Comment: This wont't work if the shortcode has arguments. If you really want to go this way, which is slow, use WP's `get_shortcode_regex()` for searching.

Comment: Like I said, "potential" answer that I haven't tested yet ... :-)

Comment: That's basically the same as method 2, but it still doesn't check the template for do_shortcode() calls.

Comment: Why it would need to do that? If you call `do_shortcode()` manually in the template then you already know you will be running the shortcode

Comment: I'm not the one calling the shortcode, the user is. This is for a distributed plugin, not a private one.

Comment: ok, so this is why you want valid markup :) You're saying that your plugin instructs the user to edit template files and call that function? Then unless you create your own PHP parser, there's no way you can know where and when that function is being called...

Comment: I always want valid markup, no matter what the circumstance... The plugin doesn't tell the user to call the function, but it's always an option. A user can always call any shortcode by either typing it into a post/page content area, or just calling do_shortcode() in a template, so both situations have to be handled. And I don't think I need to write my own PHP parser, I just need to parse the template file assigned to the current page (if there is one) to see if the shortcode is inside it.

Comment: Assuming that you could find out which template file is being used by the current page (which I doubt), how would you parse it without a parser? regexes? What if the line with the code is commented? There are dozones of ways to comment PHP code

Comment: The assigned template is just stored in the post_meta table, what's so hard about finding it out? You can hook into the_posts to get access to the current $post before anything is output. By 'PHP parser' I assumed you meant the entire engine, not just a strpos or regex function. Commented lines are an edge case that I'm not really worried about.

Comment: your confusing page (as in the page post-type) templates with theme files used a templates

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the default templates (e.g., single.php, home.php) as opposed to a custom template build specifically for a page (e.g., map.php), right? That's a good point. I'll bet there is a way to figure out which one is being used, but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of TheDeadMedic's answer and the get_shortcode_regex() [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) (which actually didn't find my shortcodes), I created a simple function used to enqueue scripts for multiple shortcodes. Since the wp_enqueue_script() in shortcodes only adds to the footer, this can be helpful as it can handle both header and footer scripts.

```
function add_shortcode_scripts() {
    global $wp_query;   
    $posts = $wp_query->posts;
    $scripts = array(
        array(
            'handle' => 'map',
            'src' => 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
            'deps' => '',
            'ver' => '3.0',
            'footer' => false
        ),
        array(
            'handle' => 'contact-form',
            'src' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery.validate.min.js',
            'deps' => array( 'jquery' ),
            'ver' => '1.11.1',
            'footer' => true
        )   
    );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        foreach ( $scripts as $script ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#\[ *' . $script['handle'] . '([^\]])*\]#i', $post->post_content ) ) {
                // enqueue css and/or js
                if ( wp_script_is( $script['handle'], 'registered' ) ) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    wp_register_script( $script['handle'], $script['src'], $script['deps'], $script['ver'], $script['footer'] );
                    wp_enqueue_script( $script['handle'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'add_shortcode_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I also found a solution for conditional css loading which works for my plugin [www.mapsmarker.com](http://www.mapsmarker.com) and I´d like to share with you. It checks if my shortcode is used within the current template file and header/footer.php and if yes, enqueues the needed stylesheet in the header:

```
  function prefix_template_check_shortcode( $template ) {
    $searchterm = '[mapsmarker';
    $files = array( $template, get_stylesheet_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'header.php', get_stylesheet_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'footer.php' );
    foreach( $files as $file ) {
        if( file_exists($file) ) {
            $contents = file_get_contents($file);
            if( strpos( $contents, $searchterm )  ) {
                wp_enqueue_style('
leafletmapsmarker', LEAFLET_PLUGIN_URL . 'leaflet-dist/leaflet.css');
                  break; 
            }
        }
    }
  return $template;
  }  
  add_action('template_include','prefix_template_check_shortcode' );
```

Comment: bit of an aside but doesn't this assume that people are using header.php and footer.php. What about theme wrapping methods such those described by http://scribu.net/wordpress/theme-wrappers.html ? or themes like roots that keep their template parts elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

For my plugin I found that sometimes users have a theme builder that has shortcode stored in **post meta data**. Here is what I am using to detect whether my plugin shortcode is present in current **post or post meta data**:

```
function abcd_load_my_shorcode_resources() {
       global $post, $wpdb;

       // determine whether this page contains "my_shortcode" shortcode
       $shortcode_found = false;
       if ( has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'my_shortcode') ) {
          $shortcode_found = true;
       } else if ( isset($post->ID) ) {
          $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta " .
            "WHERE post_id = %d and meta_value LIKE '%%my_shortcode%%'", $post->ID ) );
          $shortcode_found = ! empty( $result );
       }

       if ( $shortcode_found ) {
          wp_enqueue_script(...);
          wp_enqueue_style(...);
       }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'abcd_load_my_shorcode_resources' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> because CSS should be declared inside `<head>`

For CSS files you can load them within your shortcode output:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import "path/to/your.css"; 
</style>
```

Set a constant or something after this, like `MY_CSS_LOADED` (only include the CSS if the constant is not set).

Both your methods are slower than going this way.

For JS files you can do the same if the script you're loading is unique and doesn't have any outside dependencies. If this is not the case load it inside the footer, but use the constant to determine if needs to be loaded or not...

Comment: Loading CSS outside the `<head>` element isn't proper markup. True, validation is just a guideline, but if we're trying to stick to that guideline it makes loading the stylesheet within the shortcode output a bad idea.

Comment: Inline CSS blocks are valid markup, even in XHTML from what I remember. There's no reason not to use them when you have no other acceptable alternative

Comment: According to W3C's validation tool: `<style type="text/css">
The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head"`.  So inline styles (`<element style="..."></element>`) are valid, but inline `<style>` elements aren't.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's a possibility, but it's considered a bad practice. It could cause FOUC, force the browser to re-render the page and fail the W3C validator. It also won't work with wp_enqueue_style(), making it impossible for other theme/plugin developers to easily substitute their own script/styles.

Comment: @EAMann. True, my mistake, I thought it would validate. Still, W3C validation means nothing...

Comment: @One Trick Pony Um... It means something to me. And it means something to every other developer that I respect. I don't follow it blindly, but it'd be rare for me to consider anything that breaks standards to be an acceptable answer.

Comment: If you don't follow it blindly, then can you provide reasons why this practice is bad ?

Comment: I gave 4 reasons in my comment above...

Comment: It's considered a bad practice but this is precisely what WordPress core's gallery shortcode does: Print a css block inline. It's a bit better than using the style attribute and works. My plugin that has a shortcode just prints the css to the head on every view. There's not a lot of it :)

Comment: @mfields, if I do that then other theme/plugin developers can't replace the files with their own. It doesn't matter if the core does it, it's still a bad practice.

Comment: make it filterable and any other plugin or theme can do as they like with it. If they configure the filter to return an empty string - nothing will be printed.

Comment: You didn't mention any objective reasons against this practice. Anyway it doesn't matter; I only see two options here: Always load CSS/scripts (optimize them for size), or conditional inline styles

Comment: @mfields, that's a good point, but I prefer the enqueue_style approach.

Comment: @One Trick Pony, I think you're wrong, but I'm tired of arguing about it.