# admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request) what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ajax

I want to include a custom code into a page with dynamic selects. I am using code snippets plugin to write PHP. But I am stuck right now with a 400 ajax error when I try to select a value. I have been struggling with this problem for some time now and have tried a lot of things, dumbed down my code. I have read do many posts on this error code, I don't know where to look anymore...

The URL is on a test "live" website that you can find here: https://firehoff.vimaweb.fr/test/
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
add_shortcode('choix_produits', 'wpcode_elementor_shortcode');

function wpcode_elementor_shortcode($atts) {
    global $wpdb;
    $admin_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    echo "<form action=\"$admin_url\" method=\"post\" class=\"\">";
    
    echo '<select name="marques" id="marques">';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct(marque) FROM wpfir_module_bougies;");

    if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($row->marque) . '">' . esc_html($row->marque) . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Aucune donnée trouvée</option>';
    }
    
    echo '</select>';
        
    echo '<select name="modeles" id="modeles"><option value="">Sélectionnez un modèle</option></select>';
    
    echo '</form>'; 
    
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('my_nonce_action');

    // Ajout du script
    wp_register_script('script_bougies', content_url() . '/plugins/bougies/script_bougies.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('script_bougies', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),'nonce' => $nonce));
    wp_enqueue_script('script_bougies');
        
    add_action('wp_ajax_get_modeles', 'get_modeles_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_modeles', 'get_modeles_callback');

    function get_modeles_callback() {
        /*$marque_selected = esc_sql($_POST['marque']);
        //error_log("marque : ".print_r( $marque_selected, true ) );
        $modeles = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT distinct(modele) FROM wpfir_module_bougies where marque = %s", $marque_selected));

        if ($modeles) {
            $options_html = '';
            foreach ($modeles as $modele) {
                $options_html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($modele->modele) . '">' . esc_html($modele->modele) . '</option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option value=''>Aucune donnée trouvée</option>";
        }
        
        

        echo $options_html;*/
        echo "<option value=''>test</option>";
        wp_die();
    }


}
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $('#marques').on('change', function() {
        var marqueSelected = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {
                action: "get_modeles", 
                marque: marqueSelected,
                nonce: ajax_object.nonce
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert('youpi');
                $('#modeles').html(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(status + ': ' + error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Edit : alright, I did some progress thanks to you, now it's working but I can only display 456 inside my select. I need to dig to see why I can't put html or $ inside the echo, for now only echo 456; works.

Edit 2 : nailed it! Thank you all for your patience, I can now work on content ;)

Comment: As an aside this would work as a REST endpoint instead of an admin AJAX endpoint, and I think that's the more 'modern' way of doing this. That said admin AJAX isn't going away either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the AJAX handler inside the shortcode handler. That's not going to work: admin AJAX requests aren't processed in the context of a page, so the shortcode won't be run, so the handler won't be set up.

You'll need to move the function definition and add_actions out to the top level, not inside wpcode_elementor_shortcode.

Your script enqueues also look wrong too: they're supposed to be called from a wp_enqueue_scripts hook handler, which will be called before you know whether they're actually needed on a page - AFAIK [there's no good solution to only including scripts on the right pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20854/3276). That said, you might get away with that here if the script is set to be included in the footer (which it's not at first glance) and the dependencies just work out too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In the link you posted, if you go a little further, he created another post in 2012 that says (if I understood correctly) it's possible to declare the handler inside the shortcode handler since Wordpress 3.3. https://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html
If not, where do I put the declaration? I tried in the function.php, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh well, I managed to put it inside function.php, but I still have a 400 error.

Comment: Huh, maybe I'm wrong then: if the script enqueuing was already working for you then great, probably fine as-is.

Comment: However that definitely won't work for the AJAX handler which will need to be declared outside the shortcode handler.

Comment: I also tried to put the callback inside the function.php, but when I do, it doesn't do anything when I trigger the change.

Comment: :-/ Well that ought to be the fix. Do you have anything in the server logs for the 400 error? I'd throw in extra debug trace into admin-ajax.php to work out what's going wrong if it's not obvious. There are three `wp_die( '0', 400 );` s in there, so it would be useful to know which one you're hitting at least.

Comment: Well, I didn't have any errors since I moved everything to functions.php, and now I have 500 errors...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to make the call work. I still have a small issue, but at least the ajax seems to be working. Now I need to be able to put html in it... I edited the main post.